# Value of expression $x^2+y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For real numbers $x, y$, the equation $(x+y)^2=(x+3)(y-3)$ holds. What is the value of $x^2+y^2$?

a) $8$; b) $13$; c) $18$; d) $20$; e) something else

I can see it is 18 ($x=-3$, $y=3$), but I need a proof.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is putting it in the form: $ x^2+x (y+3)+(y-3) y+9=0$ then spotting that $y=3$ makes the term $y(y-3)$ zero therefore allowing you to simply it to $x^2+6 x+9=0$ which gives solution $x=-3$ as you need; but it doesn't really seem much different to just spotting that it works in the form $(x+y)^2=(x+3)(x-3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding it gives us $ x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3y - 3x - 9 $.

We recognize this as a conic section, but the axis are tilted, which generally makes it harder for us to understand. We apply an orthogonal change of coordinates. The quadratic terms are $ x^2 + xy + y^2$, and hence we want to use the orthogonal vectors $ X = x+y $ and $ Y = x-y$.

The above equation is then equivalent to:

$$ 3(x+y)^2 + (x-y+6)^2 = 0. $$

Hence, the solution (if any exists) must satisfy $x + y = 0 $ and $ x -y + 6 = 0$. This gives the unique solution $ x = -3, y = 3$.

Comment: Could you edit the firs line to $ x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3y - 3x - 9$ ? I tried but "it" wount accept.

Answer (score 2):

Following Jay's comments, $\Delta=(y+3)^2-4(y(y-3)+9)=-3(y-3)^2 \ge 0 \implies y=3$